# What do these commands mean?

Tags: linux, bash

What would be a more straight forward readable way of these commands?

And why `exit 255` and not `exit 1`?

```
[ $# -eq 3 ] || { echo error ; exit 255 ; }

grep -q "string" && exit 0
```

Comment: read about short circuiting operators

Comment: Things like `$#` are unfortunately difficult to find in the bash documentation. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20272085/827263).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others have already mentioned that `$#` is the number of command-line arguments, so I'll ignore that part of your question.

**Given `cmd1 && cmd2`**, the shell first executes `cmd1`.  If `cmd1` fails, the entire expression fails.  If `cmd1` succeeds, the shell proceeds to execute `cmd2`.  The entire expression succeeds if *both* `cmd1` and `cmd2` succeed.  So, the `&&` operator is the short-circuiting boolean AND applied to shell commands.  Uses of this operator can be replaced with

```
if cmd1
then
    cmd2
fi
```

**Given `cmd1 || cmd2`**, the shell first executes `cmd1`.  If it succeeds, the entire expression succeeds.  Otherwise, the shell executes `cmd2` and the success or failure of the expression is determined by `cmd2`.  In short, this is the short-circuiting boolean OR applied to shell commands.  You can replace this form with

```
if ! cmd1
then
    cmd2
fi
```

I've carefully used the phrases *succeeded* / *succeeds* and *failed* / *fails* above.  Success, for shell commands, is defined as a process exit status of zero.  Failure is any non-zero status.  However, attempting to understand the `&&` and `||` operators in terms of exit statuses is, at least to me, confusing since you end up with a weird sort of inverted logic.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty much straight forward, actually.

The script checks if it gets exactly 3 partameters, thats the `[ $# -eq 3 ]` part. If not, then the `{ echo error ; exit 255 ; }` part will be executed. The exit code 255 has a special meaning, it means "Exit status out of range" [see](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) here. I think it's a bit missapplied here, but possible.

Answer (score 2):

**$#** is the *number of arguments* to the shell. So, the first line says "exit if there are not 3 arguments", because the right part (after the **||**) is only executed, if the left part is not true. **||** is the logical **or**.

255 as a return code may be arbitrary.

the scripts will return **0**, if the word "string" is in the input.

Does this help?

Comment: Exit codes are not entirely arbitrary, especially 255 is not arbitrary!

Answer (score 1):

On one side of the or operator you have the test ( [ ) function, if this evaluates to true (which it will when $# is equal to three) then we don't even need to bother checking the otherside. If it's false, we have to try the other side, which in this case is a function to echo an error and then exit. The same functionality could be accomplished with a more verbose script:

```
if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
  echo error
  exit 255
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The line with the `grep` command does `exit 0` if "string" is in the input, otherwise the exit code will be 1.
A more explicit way would be:

```
grep -q "string"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  exit 0
else
  exit 1
fi
```